# seniority:manager and seniority:management should be synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

If at all possible, looking for a position with `seniority:manager` should result in the same set as `seniority:management`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a tag (so doesn't support synonyms); it's a defined list of values. Unfortunately we forgot to document what the valid values were on the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search-jobs).

I've just done that, so thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Why are those two different values? What does that difference mean?

Comment: `seniority:management` has never been a supported value.